# Pandas.Unstack Python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, reshape

I have a dataframe consisting of several medical measurements taken at different hours (from 1 to 12) and from different patients.
The data is organised by two indices, one corresponding to the patient number (pid) and one to the time of the measurements.
The measurements themselves are in the columns.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
            | Measurement1 |... |Measurement35
pid | Time  |              |    |
-------------------------------------------------------
1    1      | Meas1@T1,pid1|    |     Meas35@T1,pid1
     2      |  Meas@T2,pid1|    |     Meas35@T2,pid1
     3      |    ...       |    |           ...
     ...    |              |    |
     12.    |              |    |
            |              |    |
2    1.     | Meas1@T1,pid2|    |           ... 
     2.     |              |    |
     3.     |              |    |
     ...    |        ...   |    |
     12.    |              |    |
...         |              |    |
9999 1.     |              |    |           ...
     2.     |              |    |
     3.     |              |    |
     ...    |              |    |           ...
     12.    |              |    |
```

And what I would like to get is one row for each patients and one column per each combination of Time and measurement (so the pid row contains all the data relative to that patient):

```
    |    Measurement1    |... |    Measurement35   |
pid | T1 | T2 | ... | T12|    |T1 | T2 | ... | T12 |
-------------------------------------------------------
1   |    |    |     |    |    |   |    |     |     |
2   |    |    |     |    |    |   |    |     |     |
... |    |    |     |    |    |   |    |     |     |
9999|    |    |     |    |    |   |    |     |     |
```

What I tried is to use `DF.pivot(index ='pid', columns='Time')` but I get 35 columns per each Measurement instead of 12 columns that I need (and the values in these 35 columns are sometimes shifted). Similar works with `DF.unstack(1)`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the argument 'values' inside df.pivot

```
# df example
df = {'pid':[1 for _ in range(12)]+[2 for _ in range(12)]+[3 for _ in range(12)],'Time':[x+1 for x in range(12)]+[x+1 for x in range(12)]+[x+1 for x in range(12)],'Measurement1':['val_time1',np.nan,'val_time3',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'val_time7','val_time8','val_time9',np.nan,np.nan,'val_time12']+['val_time1',np.nan,'val_time3',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'val_time7','val_time8','val_time9',np.nan,np.nan,'val_time12']+['val_time1',np.nan,'val_time3',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'val_time7','val_time8','val_time9',np.nan,np.nan,'val_time12'], 'Measurement2':['val_time1',np.nan,'val_time3',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'val_time7','val_time8','val_time9',np.nan,np.nan,'val_time12']+['val_time1',np.nan,'val_time3',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'val_time7','val_time8','val_time9',np.nan,np.nan,'val_time12']+['val_time1',np.nan,'val_time3',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,'val_time7','val_time8','val_time9',np.nan,np.nan,'val_time12']}

Out:
        pid  Time Measurement1 Measurement2
0     1     1    val_time1    val_time1
1     1     2          NaN          NaN
2     1     3    val_time3    val_time3
3     1     4          NaN          NaN
4     1     5          NaN          NaN
5     1     6          NaN          NaN
6     1     7    val_time7    val_time7
7     1     8    val_time8    val_time8
8     1     9    val_time9    val_time9
9     1    10          NaN          NaN
10    1    11          NaN          NaN
11    1    12   val_time12   val_time12
12    2     1    val_time1    val_time1
13    2     2          NaN          NaN
14    2     3    val_time3    val_time3
15    2     4          NaN          NaN
```

Pivoting specifying that we want to use values for both columns, Measurement1 and 2

```
df_pivoted = df.pivot(index='pid', columns='Time', values=['Measurement1','Measurement2'])

Out:
     Measurement1                       ... Measurement2                      
Time           1    2          3    4   ...           9    10   11          12
pid                                     ...                                   
1       val_time1  NaN  val_time3  NaN  ...    val_time9  NaN  NaN  val_time12
2       val_time1  NaN  val_time3  NaN  ...    val_time9  NaN  NaN  val_time12
3       val_time1  NaN  val_time3  NaN  ...    val_time9  NaN  NaN  val_time12
```

Check to see if we have 12 sub columns for each Measurement group:

```
print(df_pivoted.columns.levels)

Out:
[['Measurement1', 'Measurement2'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
```